# Como fazer tabela baseado no layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou querendo fazer uma tabela de duas colunas, mas estou com dificuldade.Não consigo alinhar a tabela corretamente como na imagem. O título das colunas alinhados ao final, as linhas separadas com bordas com e com o texto alinhado no final. O tamanho das minhas colunas ficam desproporcionais. Eu queria uma solução para minha tabela ficar igual na imagem.

Quero fazer igual na imagem abaixo:
[image: table]

Ainda não adicionei uma estilização completa, mas minha estrutura está assim:

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Loja</th>
                    <th>Faturamento</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 1</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Loja 2</td>
                    <td>12.000,00</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

O CSS está assim:

```
 export const Container = styled.div`
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 22%;
   height: 22%;

   table {
       width: 100%;
       border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
       border-collapse: collapse;
   }

    th, td {
       text-align: left;
       /* width: 70%; */
       border: 1px solid black;
   }
`
```

Comment: É um pouco difícil dizer a melhor solução sem conhecer o problema por completo e a solução que estás integrando. Há algum problema com a abordagem que tentaste?

Comment: Editei a mensagem, desculpe por não ser claro.

Comment: Também não entendi o problema. Mas uma coisa é clara: se você tem dados tabulares, como parece ter, a forma correta/semântica de estruturar é com `<table>`, não com `<div>`.

Comment: O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer a tabela como está na imagem

Comment: Sim, você quer fazer a tabela que nem na imagem, porém no título está "Melhor maneira", mas em que sentido? Layout, semântica, acessibilidade e etc?

Comment: É em layout, editei o título  haha. Eu só preciso de uma solução para fazer a minha tabela igual na imagem que postei. Está quase, mas não consigo alinhar a tabela e separar as colunas.

Comment: @Stlick, se você quer alinhar o conteúdo da tabela que nem na imagem você pode usar a pseudo-classe [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) para pegar determinados elementos. O código ficaria algo como `tr th:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(2) {text-align: right;}`.

Comment: Veja se estes links te ajudam: https://jsfiddle.net/j8vazynk/2/ e https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Styling_tables